# Change of measure between T-forward and T*-forward contract?

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, martingale, libor, forward-rate, numerairechange

I am trying to prove the need of a convexity adjustment to a forward rate by calculating the next expectation:

\begin{align*}
P(t_0, T_s)E^{T_s}\big(L(T_s, T_s, T_e) \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_0}\big).
\end{align*}

Where $E^{T_s}$ denotes the expectation under a T-measure with $P(t,T_s)$ as numéraire and $t_0< T_s < T_e $ and $L(T_s, T_s, T_e)$ is the libor rate observed in $T_s$ for the period between $T_s$ and $T_e$

To do it I would like to apply a change of measure so that I can calculate the expectation under a T*-measure with $P(t,T_e)$ as numéraire.

I know to do this change of measure I need to know the Radon-Nikodym derivative, so I need something like this:

\begin{align*}
P(t_0, T_s)E^{T_s}\big(L(T_s, T_s, T_e) \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_0}\big)=P(t_0, T_s)E^{T_e}\big(\frac{dQ^{T_s}}{dQ^{T_e}}L(T_s, T_s, T_e) \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_0}\big)
\end{align*}
How do I know what value of $\frac{dQ^{T_s}}{dQ^{T_e}}$ changes from $Q^{T_s}$ to $Q^{T_e}$?

From what I've seen so far, the Radon-Nikodym derivative is easy to get when you have the distribution under which you are trying to calculate the expectation. For example if $X \sim N(0,1)$ with density function $f(x)$ I can calculate $E[X]$ the usual integral way, or I can introduce a measure $G$ where $g(x)$ can be the density function of say $X \sim N(0,100)$ and it would be the same if I calculate $E_g[X\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}]$ so here my Radon-Nikodym derivative is the division of two density functions. I've seen different publications in where this is used to change from one measure to another, but still I don't seem to understand how you know what value to use for each case, specially in the case I'm asking now since I'm not sure of the density functions I should be using.

The only thing that cross through my mind is that $L(T_s, T_s, T_e)$ is a martingale under $Q^{T_e}$. So perhaps I should assign it this dynamics $dL(t, T_s, T_e) = \sigma_s L(t, T_s, T_e) d W_t^s$ from there I can get a density function which would be like the $g(x)$ in my example. Then if I can find how $L(T_s, T_s, T_e)$ dynamics are under $Q^{T_s}$ maybe I could get the $f(x)$ and the division would be my Radon-Nikodym?

Much help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $Q^{T_s}$ is risk neutral for the numeraire $P(t,T_s)$, and $Q^{T_e}$ is risk neutral for the numeraire $P(t,T_e)$, hence
$$
\left(\frac{dQ^{T_s}}{dQ^{T_e}}\right)_t = \frac{P(t,T_s)}{P(t,T_e)} \frac{P(t_0,T_e)}{P(t_0,T_s)}
$$
In the specific case that you are looking at you are computing the forward in-arrears fixing Libor (in arrears because fixed and paid on $T_s$) so what you need is
$$
\left(\frac{dQ^{T_s}}{dQ^{T_e}}\right)_{T_s} = \frac{P(T_s,T_s)}{P(T_s,T_e)} \frac{P(t_0,T_e)}{P(t_0,T_s)} = \frac{1}{P(T_s,T_e)} \frac{P(t_0,T_e)}{P(t_0,T_s)}
$$
In a **single curve** settings you have by definition of the Libor rate
$$
P(T_s,T_e) = \frac{1}{1+L(T_s, T_s, T_e) \text{yearfrac}(T_s,T_e)}
$$
hence
$$
\left(\frac{dQ^{T_s}}{dQ^{T_e}}\right)_{T_s} =\left(1+L(T_s, T_s, T_e) \text{yearfrac}(T_s,T_e)\right) \frac{P(t_0,T_e)}{P(t_0,T_s)}
$$
and
$$
E^{T_s}\left[L(T_s, T_s, T_e) \right] = \frac{P(t_0,T_e)}{P(t_0,T_s)} E^{T_e}\left[L(T_s, T_s, T_e) \left(1+L(T_s, T_s, T_e) \text{yearfrac}(T_s,T_e)\right)\right] \\
 = E^{T_e}\left[L(T_s, T_s, T_e) \right] + cvx
$$
with
$$
cvx = \frac{P(t_0,T_e)}{P(t_0,T_s)} E^{T_e}\left[L(T_s, T_s, T_e) \left(1+L(T_s, T_s, T_e) \text{yearfrac}(T_s,T_e)- \frac{P(t_0,T_s)}{P(t_0,T_e)} \right)\right] 
$$
This is the theoretical convexity adjustment.

To compute the adjustment you need a model for $L(T_s, T_s, T_e)$. For instance if you assume that $L(T_s, T_s, T_e)$ is log normal or displaced log normal with constant volatility you easily obtain a closed form solution.

Or if you assume that prices of caplets/floorlets on $L(T_s, T_s, T_e)$ with natural payment date $T_e$ are available for all strikes you can compute the adjustment using **replication and the Carr-Madan formula**. The latter is the standard procedure for in-arrears swaps / caps / floors.

In a **dual curve** settings you can easily adapt the above formulas by assuming for instance that the Libor-OIS basis is deterministic.

Also in real life for most markets (notable exception is GBP) a Libor that covers the period $T_s$ to $T_e$ fixes on $T_s - 2$ business days, but the approach above still applies.

Comment: hey, @Antoine Conze thanks for the info. I'm still lost with the Radon-Nikodym derivative part, could you give me more insight on it? how do you calculate it? My problem is that I'm looking for probabilities in the RHS of the equation but all I'm understanding is that I have discount factors $\left(\frac{dQ^{T_s}}{dQ^{T_e}}\right)_t = \frac{P(t,T_s)}{P(t,T_e)} \frac{P(t_0,T_e)}{P(t_0,T_s)}$

Comment: RN derivative is just a random variable: $dQ^{T_s}/dQ^{T_e} = Z$ means $E^{T_s}[X] = E^{T_e}[Z X]$ for any $X$. You don't necessarily have to introduce the density of $Z$ to perform calculations.

Comment: thanks again. @Antoine Conze I get that RN derivative helps us move from one probability measure to another. What I don't understand is how you know that in this case $\left(\frac{dQ^{T_s}}{dQ^{T_e}}\right)_t$ equals $\frac{P(t,T_s)}{P(t,T_e)} \frac{P(t_0,T_e)}{P(t_0,T_s)}$ ? that's the part I can't figure out. Is it that for some reason $dQ^{T_s}= \frac{P(t,T_s)}{P(t,T_e)}$ and $dQ^{T_e}= \frac{P(t_0,T_s)}{P(t_0,T_e)}$ ?

Comment: I kept searching and found on [here](https://www.math.nyu.edu/~alberts/spring07/Lecture3.pdf) that radon-Nikodym derivative is given by the ratio of the numeraires. Is that what you are using to calculate it?

Comment: Yes. A Probability measure $Q$ is RN for a numeraire $N(t)$ iif $S(t)/N(t)$ is martingale under $Q$ for any asset $S(t)$. Therefore if $Q$ is RN for $N(t)$ and $Q'$ is RN for $N'(t)$ then $E^Q[S(t)/N(t)]=S(0)/N(0)$ and $E^{Q'}[S(t)/N'(t)]=S(0)/N'(0)$ for any asset $S(t)$, hence $E^{Q'}[S(t)/N'(t)]= E^Q[S(t)/N(t)]N(0)/N'(0)$ for any asset $S(t)$, hence $dQ'/dQ=(N'(t)/N(t)) \times (N(0)/N'(0))$

Comment: thanks @Antoine Conze, I've been thinking about it. Now I get how the calculation is done. One last thing bugs me, just to confirm... to do this change I understand that we are assuming that  $L(0, T_s, T_e)=P(t_0, T_s)E^{T_s}\big(\frac{L(T_s, T_s, T_e)}{P(T_s, T_s)} \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_0}\big)$ is true, and also $L(0, T_s, T_e)=P(t_0, T_e)E^{T_e}\big(\frac{L(T_s, T_s, T_e)}{P(t_s, T_e)} \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_0}\big)$ is true, with some specific dynamics for $L(t, T_s, T_e)$ which are different under each measure for this to equalities to be true

Comment: So we want to solve this expectation under $Q^{T_s}$ because the payment is due to $T_s$ but we don't know the dynamics of $L(t, T_s, T_e)$ under this measure, hence we change to another measure, $Q^{T_e}$ under which we know $L(0, T_s, T_e)=E^{T_e}\big(L(T_s, T_s, T_e)\mid \mathcal{F}_{t_0}\big)$, and there we assume some model for $L(T_s, T_s, T_e)$ to solve the expectation. So my question is, couldn't we have assumed the model for $L(T_s, T_s, T_e)$ from the beginning in which case no convexity adjustment would be needed?

Comment: The "model" for $L(T_s,T_s,T_e)$ under $Q^{T_s}$ needs to be arbitrage free, therefore 1) it should be compatible with the natural forward libor $E^{Q^{T_e}}[L(T_s,T_s,T_e)]$ which we compute directly from the projection curve bootstrapped to FRAs/Swaps/etc. and 2) it should be compatible with available natural payment dates caplets/floorlets quotes. That is why computing $E^{Q^{T_s}}[L(T_s,T_s,T_e)]$ using replication is the preferred method as it uses all available market information.

Comment: So it might be possible to do it that way, however I might need to find the right "model" for $L(T_s,T_s,T_e)$ under $Q^{T_s}$ under some assumptions which might also need some estimation of parameters (i.e. volatility) and would be odd to estimate this parameters from the available information in the market. And it does feel more natural and compatible to change to a measure in which the market information is available and work from there. Thank you

Comment: Hi Antoine, I am getting a slight different convexity adjustment to yours, are you sure you are not missing the term $$\frac{P(t_0,T_e)}{P(t_0,T_s)}$$ in your expression for $cvx$ ?  PS: I attach my solution as a separate answer below.

Comment: yes you are correct. An additional check is that one should recover cvx = 0 when rates are deterministic. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question can be solved easier. You may ask me why. Here is my answer:

First of all the LIBOR forward rate $L(t, t, T)$ is $\mathbb{Q}^{T}$-martingale, where $\mathbb{Q}^{T}$ is a $T-$forward measure defined with the following Ranon-Nikidym derivative structure:

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\frac{d\mathbb{Q}^T}{d\mathbb{P}} = \frac{e^{-\int_{0}^{T}\, r_u du}}{P(0, T)}
\end{equation}

Therefore, using the standard definition for the spot forward LIBOR rate we have that

\begin{equation}
P(0, T)\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^T}\Big(L(t,t, T)\Big) = P(0, t)\times L(0, t, T) = P(0, t)\times\frac{1}{\Delta}\Big(\frac{P(0, t)}{P(0, T)}-1\Big),
\end{equation}
where $\Delta = T-t$, and $P(0, t)$ and $P(0, T)$ are zero-coupon bond prices with different maturity times.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually getting a slightly different convexity adjustment to Antoine's:

For clarity of notation, I use: $T_s=T_1$, $T_e=T_2$ and $yearfrac(T_1,T_2)=\tau$.

We then have (by definition of Radon-Nikodym derivative):

$$\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_1}}_{t_0}\left[L(T_1, T_1, T_2)\right]=\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[\frac{\partial Q_{T_1}}{\partial Q_{T_2}}L(T_1, T_1, T_2)\right]$$

The Radon-Nikodym derivative is then computed as:

$$\frac{\partial Q_{T_1}}{\partial Q_{T_2}}(T_1)|t_0=\frac{P(t_0,T_2)}{P(t_0,T_1)}\frac{P(T_1,T_1)}{P(T_1,T_2)}=\frac{P(t_0,T_2)}{P(t_0,T_1)}(1+\tau L(T_1,T_1,T_2))$$

*(so far our results agree)*

And substituting the above into the expectation, we get:

$$\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[\frac{\partial Q_{T_1}}{\partial Q_{T_2}}L(T_1, T_1, T_2)\right]=\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[\frac{P(t_0,T_2)}{P(t_0,T_1)}(1+\tau L(T_1,T_1,T_2))L(T_1, T_1, T_2)\right]=\\=\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[\frac{P(t_0,T_2)}{P(t_0,T_1)}L(T_1,T_1,T_2)+\frac{P(t_0,T_2)}{P(t_0,T_1)}\tau L(T_1,T_1,T_2)^2\right]=\\=$$

Now adding $0=+\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[L(T_1,T_1,T_2)\right]-\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[L(T_1,T_1,T_2)\right]$, we get:

$$=\\=\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[\frac{P(t_0,T_2)}{P(t_0,T_1)}L(T_1,T_1,T_2)+\frac{P(t_0,T_2)}{P(t_0,T_1)}\tau L(T_1,T_1,T_2)^2\right]+\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[L(T_1,T_1,T_2)\right]-\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[L(T_1,T_1,T_2)\right]=\\=\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[\frac{P(t_0,T_2)}{P(t_0,T_1)}L(T_1,T_1,T_2)+\frac{P(t_0,T_2)}{P(t_0,T_1)}\tau L(T_1,T_1,T_2)^2-L(T_1,T_1,T_2)\right]+\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[L(T_1,T_1,T_2)\right]=\\=\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[\frac{P(t_0,T_2)}{P(t_0,T_1)}L(T_1,T_1,T_2)\left(1+\tau L(T_1,T_1,T_2)-\frac{P(t_0,T_1)}{P(t_0,T_2)} \right)\right]+\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[L(T_1,T_1,T_2)\right]=\\=\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[L(T_1,T_1,T_2)\right]+cvx$$

From the above, it follows that:

$$cvx=\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[\frac{P(t_0,T_\color{red}2)}{P(t_0,T_\color{red}1)}L(T_1,T_1,T_2)\left(1+\tau L(T_1,T_1,T_2)-\frac{P(t_0,T_\color{red}1)}{P(t_0,T_\color{red}2)} \right)\right]$$

As opposed to:

$$cvx=\mathbb{E}^{Q_{T_2}}_{t_0}\left[L(T_1,T_1,T_2)\left(1+\tau L(T_1,T_1,T_2)-\frac{P(t_0,T_\color{red}2)}{P(t_0,T_\color{red}1)} \right)\right]$$